# Unable to deploy proxy to apigee using apigeetool

Tags: node.js, jenkins, apigee

Thanks joey,                                                                                                I am using the below commands from Jenkins but getting errors.

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Import-Module PowerShellGet
Install-Module -Name PSApigeeEdge -Force
Import-module PSApigeeEdge
Set-EdgeConnection -org def -User xyz-EncryptedPassword abc
Deploy-EdgeApi -Name proxy-name -Environment digital-dev -Revision 25    Error:                                                                                                                     ConvertTo-SecureString : Input string was not in a correct format.
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSApigeeEdge\Public\Set-EdgeConnection.ps1:97 char:35
+                     $SecurePass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $EncryptedPassw ...
+                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertTo-SecureString], FormatException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.FormatException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToSecureStringCommand
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another tool you can use if you are comfortable with powershell. 
https://github.com/DinoChiesa/Edge-Powershell-Admin

The powershell module will need to be imported in order to work with the module, which is pretty simple in jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

[ADT](https://github.com/ashishkpathak/adt) can help deploy apiproxies/shared-flows. It has detailed documentation on setting up and using the tool.